# Yielding from recursive helper function

Tags: python

I want to yield the results from a recursive function (code below) but am having difficulties getting the output to match what I want. Ideally, if I call

```py
print(list(n_queens_solutions(4)))
```

I would see

```py
[[1, 3, 0, 2], [2, 0, 3, 1]]
```

but instead the function returns

```py
[[], []]
```

I'm not too familiar with Python generators; I've tried various permutations of "yield" and "return" to no avail.

```py
def n_queens_valid(board):
    for q1 in range(len(board)):
        for q2 in range (1, len(board)-q1):
            if board[q1] == board[q1+q2] or board[q1+q2] == board[q1]+q2 or board[q1+q2] == board[q1]-q2:
                return False
    return True

def n_queens_solutions(n):
    board = []
    return n_queens_helper(0, board, n)

def n_queens_helper(n, board, size):
    if len(board) == size:
        print(board)
        yield board
    else:
        for i in range(size):
            board.append(i)
            if n_queens_valid(board):
                yield from n_queens_helper(n+1, board, size)
            board.pop()

print(list(n_queens_solutions(4)))
```

The print from the last line in the code above should output: [[1, 3, 0, 2], [2, 0, 3, 1]], but instead returns [[], []].

Comment: I think it might be because you pass the same `board`. When you create the list, all the `append` and `pop` are finally executed, on only one `board` object. try passing a copy in your recursion (e.g. `board[:]`)

Comment: @njzk2 Ah, this makes so much sense! I tried your suggestion and it worked. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's illustrate what is happening with an simpler example:

```
def my_func():
  output = [1,2,3]
  print("Output", output)
  yield output
  print("Let's now clear the output")
  output.clear()
  print("Cleared output", output)

result = my_func()
print("Result", result)
print("Result List", list(result))
```

Output:

```
Result <generator object my_func at 0x7fd7ccc2a6d0>
Output [1, 2, 3]
Let's now clear the output
Cleared output []
Result List [[]]
```

- When the function itself it called (first line of the output), nothing in the generator function is actually executed.
- When we fetch all the content from the generator (by calling `list(result)`), we run the generator until it reaches the end of the function, putting all `yield` result in the list
- As we can see, because everything in the function is now executed, the `output.clear()` method is also executed.
- The content of the `result` variable matches the content of the `output` variable at the end of the generator function

To prevent this behaviour, one easy solution is to return a copy of the value we are returning, so we can manipulate it later: `yield output[:]` (this is a shallow copy, though)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to work through a tutorial on generators to understand more fully how they work.  The problem you're facing at the moment is that `n_queens_solutions` calls the `helper` function only *once* -- that first branch fails to find a solution, and you're displaying the empty board returned upon failure.

Very briefly, think of a generator as a function with a bookmark.  When you call the generator, it executes until it hits the first `yield`; it returns that value, but retains all of its state information: all variable values, its place in the code, etc.  When you call it again, it restarts from that point and continues until it reaches the next `yield`, continuing in this fashion until it falls off the end of the code.

The simplest use of a generator is as a type of iterator:

```
for solution in n_queens_helper(...):
```

You've used it both this way (by building a list of solutions in your main program) and to recur on partial solutions (with `yield from`), but you need a little more work on the control flow.  Try inserting a tracing statement:

```
def n_queens_helper(n, board, size):
    print("ENTER helper", n, board)
    if len(board) == size:
```

Watch the progression of execution now.